# If I have one of my computers with all my storage devices and I use it like a NAS, can anyone with internet access get access to it?

Tags: security, nas

I have a spare computer that I want to make use of it.

I have 2 other computers, one is Windows 10 and the other is Linux. My daughter may use a 4th computer which is a Windows laptop.

I was thinking of installing Linux Mint Debian Edition on it and just using SSH and rsync from my other computers to access files or perform backups.

Although with my Windows computers, I'd like to setup one of the drives using NTFS so that I have storage for Windows.

Because it will be my central storage computer, I need to leave it on most of the time.

My biggest concern is whether anyone with internet access can access it. Is that possible?

And what do I need to do to prevent it, or to secure it well.

In case this helps, my modem / router (they're one) has 4 Firewall settings: Max, Typical, Min, Custom.

Right now it's on minimum.

**Maximum Security (High):**

Maximum security level would block all outgoing traffic except the applications listed in the GUI, like Internet browsing, Email service, VPN pass-through, DNS and iTunes service.

Allow (WAN-To-LAN):
HTTP and HTTPS (TCP port 80, 443)
DNS (TCP/UDP port 53)
NNTP and NTP(TCP port 119,UDP port 123)
email (TCP port 25, 110, 143, 465, 587, 993, 995)
VPN(GRE, UDP 500, TCP 1723)
iTunes (TCP port 3689)

Blocked: All unrelated WAN to LAN traffic and enable IDS.

**Typical Security (Medium):**

Blocks P2P applications, but allows all other traffic

Allow (WAN-To-LAN):All

Blocked:
IDS enabled
IDENT (port 113)

```
Peer-to-peer apps:
    kazaa - (TCP/UDP port 1214)
    bittorrent - (TCP port 6881-6999)
    gnutella- (TCP/UDP port 6346)
    vuze - (TCP port 49152-65534)
```

**Minimum Security (Low):**

No application or traffic is blocked.

Allow (WAN-To-LAN):All

Blocked:
IDS enabled
IDENT (port 113)

Comment: Ask security questions in the right forum https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, will do so as I am curious about the difference with IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like an opinion-based question.

Look at the LAN subnet you're using. Specifically, if it's IPv4 `192.168.*.*` (for any values of `*`) then your internal network cannot be accessed from outside unless you have explicitly created a hole through your router to permit it.

If you're using IPv6 then different rules apply.

---

> I was thinking of installing Linux Mint Debian Edition on it and just using SSH and rsync from my other computers to access files or perform backups.
>
> Although with my Windows computers, I'd like to setup one of the drives using NTFS so that I have storage for Windows.

That's a false assumption. If you install Samba (Windows network file shares) you can provide Windows-friendly network shares without using NTFS on your Linux-based system.

Have you looked at TrueNAS Core, FreeNAS and other similar systems? They can simplify a lot of this for you by providing a complete system.

Comment: roaima: Thanks for your answer about the subnet. Yes, my lan subnet is 192.168.*.*. So, since I didn't touch anything with my router except for setting my network Wifi password and Wifi guest password, it should be safe?

Comment: I was looking at Open Media Vault. I just don't think I need all that. And I've learned that sometimes learning the interface can be just as long to setup, particularly since I'm not looking for much except to access my drives in one place. And your note about Samba solves another issue I had. The last issue I need to review is wake-on-lan and then I'm good to go. Thanks!

Comment: The other thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using Veracrypt for 2 of my drives and OpenMediaVault doesn't support that. Well, there are manual workarounds I've read, which made me think I may as well just scrap these tools like OMV and just use Linux and install the needed tools like Samba, SSH, and so on.